# Viewing Docker CPU Usage in Grafana -- jiffies?

Tags: docker, grafana

According to the [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/#cpu-metrics-cpuacctstat), cpu is reported in *jiffies*:

> For each container, a pseudo-file cpuacct.stat contains the CPU usage
>   accumulated by the processes of the container, broken down into user
>   and system time. The distinction is:
>
> - user time is the amount of time a process has direct control of the CPU, executing process code.
> - system time is the time the kernel is executing system calls on behalf of the process.
>
> Those times are expressed in ticks of 1/100th of a second, also called
>   “user jiffies”. There are USER_HZ “jiffies” per second, and on x86
>   systems, USER_HZ is 100. Historically, this mapped exactly to the
>   number of scheduler “ticks” per second, but higher frequency
>   scheduling and tickless kernels have made the number of ticks
>   irrelevant.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to display this as some sort of "container cpu % usage" in grafana, since every metric is in the 100ks. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Math:

1. Calculate change per second = rate per second (only if you have raw jiffy value in TSDB)
2. Multiply result with 100

The result will be % CPU usage.

You can't do this kind of math in Grafana by default. This is a task for your TSDB and Grafana will just visualize calculated result returned from TSDB.

(Untested) example for InfluxDB (TSDB):

```
SELECT 
  DERIVATIVE("jiffy_value_field",1s)*100 
FROM <measurement> 
WHERE ...
```